# prove for Jacobi symbols $\sum_{k=0}^{500}(\frac{k}{1001}) = 0$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Could somebody help me prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{500}\left(\dfrac{k}{1001}\right) = 0$? I think that there might be a bijection with $\sum_{k=0}^{500}\left(\dfrac{k}{501}\right)$ but I don't know how to prove this

Comment: What do you get for $\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left(\dfrac{k}{11}\right)   \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: It is 3, but I can't see how that is relevant

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{71}\left(\dfrac{k}{143}\right) $  came out as $10$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known that $S_m = \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \left(\dfrac{k}{m}\right) = 0$, write the sum as $S_{1001} = \sum_{k = 0}^{500} \left(\dfrac{k}{1001}\right) + \sum_{k = 0}^{500} \left(\dfrac{1001 - k}{1001}\right) = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{500} \left(\dfrac{k}{1001}\right)$, therefore $\sum_{k = 0}^{500} \left(\dfrac{k}{1001}\right) = 0$

Comment: But $1001$ is not a prime.

Comment: This also holds when p is not a prime but I'd change p to something else to avoid confusion, thanks

Comment: You should explain why $\left({k\over 1001}\right)=\left({-k\over 1001}\right)$, it's certainly not true in for other moduli, such as 3.

Comment: Fair enough, I used $\left(\frac{ab}{P}\right) = \left(\frac{a}{P}\right)\left(\frac{b}{P}\right)$, and it is easy to show that $\left(\frac{-1}{1001}\right) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{b}{q}\right)$, whenever $a\equiv b\pmod q$.

Comment: Are you claiming that $\big({1\over 3}\big) = \big({3-1\over 3}\big)$?  Don't you want to place some conditions on $q$?